# Convert commented out print statements to logging calls - Python

Tags: python, regex, debugging, logging

I'm hacking on a framwork right now, and I'd like to use logging. However, the developers of the framework have been using print statements to debug, and they are all commented out for the production release. I was wondering, does anyone know of a regex to find these, and convert them to logging calls.

This is what I was thinking so far:

```
import re
import sys
import StringIO

if not len(sys.argv) != 2:
    print 'Syntax: printtologging.py file_to_process'

regex = r'#print (?P<debugstring>*)$'

output = StringIO.StringIO('w+')

def replace(match_object):
    return 'logging.debug({0})'.format(match_object.group_dict['debugstring'])

with open(sys.argv[1]) as f:
    output.writelines([re.sub(regex, replace, line) for line in f.readlines()])

output.seek(0)
print output.read()
```

Though that dosn't seem to be working. My regex's are far from brilliant, could anyone help?

Comment: I think you just need `.*` instead of `*` in the regex. (Without that change, this code doesn't run for me.)

Comment: Also, this is a one-liner in `sed` or `perl`. For example, `perl -p -i.orig -e 's/#print (.*)/logging.debug(\1)/' FILE...`. Perl is at its best when your program is one line long and you never plan to read it again. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do it in Python, consider using the [fileinput](http://docs.python.org/library/fileinput.html#module-fileinput) module:

```
import fileinput
import sys
import re

def convert(paths):
    for line in fileinput.input(paths, inplace=True, backup='~'):
        line=re.sub(r'#\s*print\s*(.*)',r'logging.debug(\1)',line)
        sys.stdout.write(line)

if __name__=='__main__':
    convert(sys.argv[1:])
```

You could call the script this way

```
% print2log.py *.py
```

It converts the scripts in-place, and makes a backup file which ends with `~`.

Note that the regex converts

```
#print 'foo'   -->  logging.debug('foo')
```

but adds an extra set of parentheses if the print statement already had one:

```
#print('foo')  --> logging.debug(('foo'))
```

It also screws up multi-line print statements:

```
#print('''foo        logging.debug(('''foo)
#bar''')       -->   #bar''')
```

Fixing this is a much harder problem, requiring parsing the comments and using something smarter than regex, which can't handle nested parentheses properly.
I think you could do it with [tokenize](http://docs.python.org/library/tokenize.html), and with code similar in spirit to [reindent.py](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Tools/scripts/reindent.py), but it would take some time and thought to get it right.

Comment: line=re.sub(r'(\s*)print\s*(.*)',r'\1logging.debug\2',line)

Comment: I changed to that, since I already had print functions AND also it adds whitespace. Without it, all the logging.debug() calls will end up leftmost in the source.

Answer (score 1):

If all the print statements are already contained in brackets, then sed will do the job:

```
sed -i s/#print/logging\.debug/g files_to_process
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the same with sed

```
sed -i.old -E -e "s/#+[[:space:]]*print (.*)/logging.debug(\1)/" FILE
```

I made your regex a bit more robust. It now also matches if multiple # and/or whitespace between # and print are present.

Note that it still doesn't handle some edge cases like

```
#print 'foo'; print'bar'
```

`-i.old` activates in-place editing with a backup written to `FILE.old`. Omit the `.old` if you don't want backups, i.e. `sed -i -E ...`

Comment: Ah, didn't know about `.old`. Very clever. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to this is to leave the print statements in place and to replace sys.stdout with a file like object that does logging.